# Enforcing production process patents

Tags: enforcement

I saw today that Ransom E. Olds patented the stationary assembly line. However, I wonder how you would enforce a patent like this unless an employee of your competitor defected. Straight off the top of my head I can think of two kinds of scenarios where enforcing a patent like this may become important:

1. Like the assembly line, where the process can be used to manufacture several different products, but owning a patent on a manufacturing process can give one business an edge over its competitors
2. Where two companies produce goods that are essentially indistinguishable, and the production process itself is the only thing that can give one company an edge in the marketplace (through, for instance, reduced cost)

So, lets consider the second scenario above. If the industry is mining, and the process is a more efficient way of extracting a metal. I reckon everybody is selling the metal at market price. Would the way to enforce this patent be to keep tabs on everyone's finances? And, is that sufficient grounds to sue someone and ask to examine the competing mine?

Comment: Industrial espionage is an option.

Comment: @EricS Yeah, but you cannot really use that to enforce a patent considering any evidence you collect will be illegal and thus not admissible in any court I know of.

Comment: Just have to hire one former employee of the other firm. Besides, you sue first and confirm the infringement during discovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying I am not a lawyer. I know even less about court proceedings. That said, if you suspect a competitor is using your patented process, I think what you do is you sue them. As part of the lawsuit is discovery where you are able to request documentation and even perform inspections. [This webpage](https://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/navigating-fact-discovery-in-a-patent-10185/) provides a thorough description of the process. Quoting from that page:

> Although less common than requests for documents, Federal Rule 34 also
> allows one party to request to inspect documents or things in
> possession of another party. For example, in a patent case, a patent
> holder may request to inspect the manufacturing process used to
> produce the accused product.

Answer (score 1):

If a large number of people are involved it is unlikely the process can be kept confidential for long.